# c# Directory.GetFiles file structure from app root

Tags: c#

I have the following piece of code:

```
string root = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
List<string> FullFileList = Directory.GetFiles(root, "*.*",
     SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(name =>
          { 
              return !(name.EndsWith("dmp") || name.EndsWith("jpg"));
          }).ToList();
```

Now this works very well, however the file names with it are quire long.
is there a way i can take out the path till root? but still show all the subfolders?

Root = C:\Users\\Desktop\Test\

But the code would return the whole path from C:
while I'd prefer if I could take out the root bit straight away. but still keep the file structure after it.

eg 
C:\Users\\Desktop\Test\hi\hello\files.txt
would return
\hi\hello\files.txt

I know i can just iterate over the file list generated and remove it all one by one, I'm wondering if I can just filter it out stright.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the power of LINQ:

```
string root = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
List<string> FullFileList = Directory.GetFiles(root, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(name =>
    { 
        return !(name.EndsWith("dmp") || name.EndsWith("jpg"));
    })
    .Select(file => file.Replace(root, "")
    .ToList();
```

Comment: ah dangit, went through the whole list and overlooked the .Select() Thank you!